# How to search for particular links in html?

Tags: php, regex, string

I am using this code

```
<?PHP

  ini_set('user_agent', 'NameOfAgent (http://www.example.net)');

  $url = "http://www.example.net/somepage.html";
  if(robots_allowed($url, "NameOfAgent")) {
    $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
    $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
    if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
      foreach($matches as $match) {
        echo $match[2];
      }
    }
  } else {
    die('Access denied by robots.txt');
  }
?>
```

to echo all link address in a html page.

Does anyone know how to modify this so that the code only lists links that begin with `"sub/"` and end with `/files/a.html`.

Comment: question is, we'd have to define `$str1` and `$str2` for you.

Comment: No, they are for me to define. You an take `$str="a"` and `$str2="b"`.

Comment: Use an assertion `(?=…)` for the href right away, or [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) in the foreach to filter them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier parsing through the elements with a parser then checking just the attribute value with a regex.

```
$html = '<html>
    <a href="a">test</a>
    <a href="atestb">test2</a>
    <a href="c">test3</a>
    </html>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if(preg_match('~^a.*b$~', $link->getAttribute('href'))){
        echo $link->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

> test2

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vI2yM4/2

This regex requires that the `href` start with `a`, (`^a`). Then has anything, (`.*`), until the ending which must end with `b`, (`b$`).

Or used in your current code (untested)...

```
<?php
// Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.
ini_set('user_agent', 'NameOfAgent (http://www.example.net)');
$url = "http://www.example.net/somepage.html";
if(robots_allowed($url, "NameOfAgent")) {
    $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($input);
    $links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        if(preg_match('~^a.*b$~', $link->getAttribute('href'))){
                echo $link->nodeValue . "\n";
        }
    }
} else {
    die('Access denied by robots.txt');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful, but my question was about href beginning with `a` and ending `b` not starting with `a` or `b`.

Comment: Oh, that is actually an easier regex, one sec.

Comment: Thank you, could `'~^a.*b$~'` be directly added to my code?

Comment: The `^` is the start of the string and the `$` is the end. The parser is drilling down to the href attribute and then the regex is checking that small bit. I don't think you could use that in your bit as it currently is written. You could use preg_replace_callback and drill into the href.. Does the parser not work for you? It probably could be done with a regex but it would/will fail at some point.